# Strange Behavior with Pictureboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am experiencing strange behavior with PictureBoxes and have narrowed down a test case.

I have four PictureBoxes on my test form.  Two have a background color set ... one red, one blue:

[image]

If I add the following code, the red Picturebox correctly parents itself to the upper Picturebox:

```
        this.redPictureBox.Parent = this.pictureBox1;
        this.redPictureBox.Location = this.pictureBox1.Location;
        this.redPictureBox.Height = this.pictureBox1.Height;
        this.redPictureBox.Width = this.pictureBox1.Width;
```

This works as expected:

[image]

However, if I add code to do the exact same thing with the blue PictureBox, nothing happens.  In fact, it appears that the second PictureBox from the top disappears altogether:

```
        this.bluePictureBox.Parent = this.pictureBox2;
        this.bluePictureBox.Location = this.pictureBox2.Location;
        this.bluePictureBox.Height = this.pictureBox2.Height;
        this.bluePictureBox.Width = this.pictureBox2.Width;
```

[image]

Why is this behavior occuring?  I must be missing something obvious but the code between the two is identical ... so why the different behavior?

Comment: Check what order they are added to the window in the `designer.cs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
this.bluePictureBox.Location = this.pictureBox2.Location;
```

You're setting the location of the blue picture box *within picture box 2* to be the location of picture box 2 relative to the container. I suspect you want:

```
this.bluePictureBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

The only reason this wasn't much of an issue for the red picture box is that picture box 1 is near the top of the screen. Even so, you can see that it's not the full height/width that it was, and it's not at the top-left of picture box 1.

Comment: Yeah this looks like your problem. You could just set Dock to DockStyle.Fill instead

Comment: @Alan: True. There are various ways of skinning this particular cat :)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was obvious ... too many hours staring at the screen!